# Automatically restore for vmdk file

Tags: linux, virtual-machines, restore

I have vmdk file of Linux server that was created by ESX or ESXi by service team. Later we will do the changes on the server but we will need to restore to existing snapshot which corresponds to stored vmdk file.

Would you please advice if there is the way to create automatic process of restoring state of the server and what tools can be used? Can we automate it without ESX using some other tools?

Update: Guys what about VirtualBox or VMWare? What do you think are differences between these virtualization management tools?

Thank you.

Comment: Your update is wildly outside the FAQ. "Update: Guys what about VirtualBox or VMWare? What do you think are differences between these virtualization management tools?"

Answer (score 0):

VMware has a set of PowerShell cmdlets which will probably help you out greatly in doing this.

Comment: thank you for reply. This is new area for me. PowerShell means they are for Windows, right? I'm looking solution for Linux. Also what these cmdlets are using, some tools? Would you give link to them?

Comment: Yes PowerShell would be used from a Windows machine.  PowerShell is built into Windows now.  I believe that the PowerShell cmdlets from VMware and installed automatically when you install the vCenter management tool.